# Writing Intel Syntax in Xcode 10.3

Tags: c, xcode, assembly, intel-syntax

I'm writing a C project in Xcode and I'd like to link a separate assembly file to be compiled along with the project. But I need the assembly to be written in Intel syntax since I find AT&T syntax absolutely grotesque.

Unfortunately, Apple's default Clang compiler doesn't like me writing my assembly code in Intel and prefers AT&T. Is there a setting I can change to allow my separate assembly file to be written in Intel syntax?

As an example, this assembles:

```
.text  
.global _func  
func:  
mov %rdx,%rax  
ret
```

But this doesn't assemble

```
.text  
.global _func  
_func:  
mov rax,rdx  
ret
```

The compiler throws errors with the latter example.

_func Is being called from the C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void func(void);
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

To clarify, I am not writing inline assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use asm intel syntax.
Just add `.intel_syntax noprefix` to begin of asm file.

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.text  
.global _func  
_func:  
mov rax,rdx  
ret
```

Comment: Ah thank you! That works. What is the noprefix for?

Comment: I think `noprefix` is disable prefix in assembly intruction.

Comment: @Nina: `noprefix` lets you write `rax` instead of `%rax` for register names, controlled separately from the rest of Intel vs. AT&T syntax mode.

Comment: @PeterCordes You are right. Link: http://web.mit.edu/rhel-doc/3/rhel-as-en-3/i386-syntax.html

Comment: @PeterCordes Interesting. I assumed intel syntax alone meant I didn't need the % before registers. Thanks for clarifying.